# http live stream server installation

Tags: swift, http

I have been putting this on the back burner as I had more immediate coding to tend to, but now I have arrived at a point where I need to use http live streaming (HLS) which is standardised by apple.

From the developer website's explanation, there is a set of CL tools to download and install on a server. Considering these are unix command line tools, I was wondering if I had to use a mac os server, which I don't have with me or any other server might do the job.

There are a lot of complicated steps to follow, but this is the basic one I would like to know. The rest is answered throughout SO, so I can handle that with the bookmarked links.

Any help greatly appreciated, or a link which I may have not found googling would be a great start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately the HLS command line tools must be installed on a Mac.

What is your end goal? Are you trying to create, encode, and host your own videos? There are many services online that specialize in this, most of which support HLS out-of-the-box, such as https://www.brightcove.com

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I have thought of using a service such as pub-nub or the one you recommended however there seems to be a limit on the number of simultaneous connections in a free mode, I thought I would undertake the process myself. I might ask my long standing web service provider if they have some mac os servers in their clusters.

Comment: @triple7 Another suggestion I would make before deciding to roll-your-own CDN is to consider an open-source alternative you can deploy to your own environment. For example, [Comcast's Traffic Control CDN](https://github.com/Comcast/traffic_control).